# Express: Unit test controller which call model mongoose model without really call the database

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mongoose, chai

I've a controller called by an Express.js router. The controller itself call mongoose model. I need to unit test the controller without calling the database and independent from the router.

Test probably should test the `res.json(err)` and `res.json(result)` response.

Page controller:

```
const pageModel = require('../model/page');

const pageController = {
    /**
     * Get all pages as a list
     * 
     * @param {*} req 
     * @param {*} res 
     * @returns {json} list of pages
     */
    getList(req, res) {
        pageModel.find({}, (err, result)=>{
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
              } else {
                res.json(result);
              }
        });
    }
};

module.exports = pageController;
```

Page model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Page Schema
const pageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    content: String,
    createdIn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updatedIn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const pageModel = mongoose.model('page', pageSchema);
module.exports = pageModel;
```

Test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PageModel = require('../../../../app/page/model/page');
const pageController = require('../../../../app/page/controller/page');
const sinon = require('sinon');

let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('Page controller', () => {

    describe('getList', () => {
        it('should return result as json object', (done) => {
            
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to my question:

First I modified the controller function `getList` to send error status

```
getList(req, res) {
    PageModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, test will test 2 things.
1- A result which return an instance of "Page" which is json object.
2- Error

Explanation:

1- Create a sinon sandbox

```
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
```

2- Mock and define: req, res, error ..etc.

```
let req = {
    body: {
        title: 'title',
        slug: 'slug',
        content: 'content'
    }
};
let res = {};
let expectedResult;
let error = new Error({error: 'error message here'});
```

3- Before each test, spy on res.json and res.status (error) and create the expected result (optional). After each test restore the sandbox.

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    res = {
        json: sandbox.spy(),
        status: sandbox.stub().returns({end: sandbox.spy()})
    };
    expectedResult = [{}, {}, {}];
});

afterEach(()=>{
    sandbox.restore();
});
```

4- In test. Stub `mongoose.Model` not `PageModel`. This way you can be sure that mongoose will not call the database (This is important as we don't do integration test). Then make sure that `PageModel` has been called and the controller function return the expected result.

```
it('should return result/page as json object', (done) => {
    sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'find').yields(null, expectedResult);
    PageController.getList(req, res);

    sinon.assert.calledWith(PageModel.find, {});
    sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, sinon.match.array);
    done();
});

it('should return error 500', (done) => {
    sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'find').yields(error);
    PageController.getList(req, res);

    sinon.assert.calledWith(PageModel.find, {});
    sinon.assert.calledWith(res.status, 500);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(res.status(500).end);
    done();
});
```

Here is the full code:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PageModel = require('../../../../app/page/model/page');
const PageController = require('../../../../app/page/controller/page');
const sinon = require('sinon');

let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('Page controller', () => {
    let req = {
        body: {
            title: 'title',
            slug: 'slug',
            content: 'content'
        }
    };
    let res = {};
    let expectedResult;
    let error = new Error({error: 'error message here'});
    
    describe('getList', () => {
        beforeEach(()=>{
            res = {
                json: sandbox.spy(),
                status: sandbox.stub().returns({end: sandbox.spy()})
            };
            expectedResult = [{}, {}, {}];
        });
    
        afterEach(()=>{
            sandbox.restore();
        });
    

        it('should return result/page as json object', (done) => {
            sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'find').yields(null, expectedResult);
            PageController.getList(req, res);

            sinon.assert.calledWith(PageModel.find, {});
            sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, sinon.match.array);
            done();
        });

        it('should return error 500', (done) => {
            sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'find').yields(error);
            PageController.getList(req, res);

            sinon.assert.calledWith(PageModel.find, {});
            sinon.assert.calledWith(res.status, 500);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(res.status(500).end);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

*Please if you find an improvement to this answer feel free to edit the answer or write your own answer*